# Linebreaks in SMTP MailMessage body

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, email, sql-server-2012

I have an ASP.NET web application that has a page that sends emails to a list of recipients. This page has an `asp:TextBox` where the body of the mail is typed in:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBody" runat="server" Height="151px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="550px" Visible="False" MaxLength="160"></asp:TextBox>
```

The page then makes use of a REST service to insert the email details into a database:

```
EmailBatchHelper.SendBatch(recipients, txtNotificationTo.Text, txtFrom.Text.TrimEnd(), txtBody.Text, txtSubject.Text, strAtt);
```

A windows service reads the emails from the database and sends them using smpt.

The problem that I'm having is the line-breaks in the body are removed somewhere along the line. I'm guessing when it gets inserted into the database. How can I have any line-breaks still be present in the message received by the user?

***Update:*** I debugged the windows service and determined that the following:

inserted into the database is the word test twice with 2 linebreaks in between. The value set to the Body of the MailMessage is the following:

```
mail.Body = "test\r\n\r\ntest";
```

Now I'm thinking there might be a setting on MailMessage to interpret linebreaks in the Body

Comment: it's better to debug the flow and figure out where the line breaks are lost than to guess

Comment: Are you sending plaintext email, or HTML mail? With the latter, line breaks like `\r\n` are essentially ignored.

Comment: @TiesonT.: I've tried both. Same result.

Comment: @TiesonT.: No, I was wrong. I was sending an HTML mail. The setting was set in 2 places and I only saw the one. That solves it, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As shown in the comments above, the most common reason for this behavior is trying to send plain text as an HTML-encoded message. The carriage return/newline characters have no meaning in HTML, so the line breaks do not show up. So, there are two quick fixes:

- Make sure the `IsBodyHtml` property is set to false on your
  `MailMessage` object(s), or
- Replace any instances of `\r\n` with `<br />` elements, then set
  `IsBodyHtml` to true. This can be done with [one simple line](http://thismightbeuseful.com/programming/c-convert-new-lines-to-br-tag-for-html-emails-from-stringbuilder/):

  `_yourEmailContent.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />").ToString();`

Another alternative is to encode/convert the newline/return characters as [entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.2):

`_yourEmailContent.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "&#x000D;&#x000A;").ToString();`